# Adding geom_vline to ggplot2 from separate data frame

Tags: r

I am having trouble adding geom_vline to my ggplot 2 chart. I am plotting on the x axis the date. as.Date format. Then on the Y axis plotting numerical values.

On the same plot. I have matching dates pulled from another data frame. They are in the same Date format as my plot above.

The problem when adding the geom_vline is that it throws a error:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

If my two dates I want to use are both Date format, im not sure why its throwing a numerical error date. The only numerial format I have is the data on the Y axis.

See code below:

```
    p1 <- ggplot(data=plotdataframe, aes(x=ddate, y=SP500close1, colour=SP500close1)) + 
  geom_vline(data=matches.df,aes(xintercept=as.numeric(ddatesmatches)))+
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title="S&P500 Close",y="S&P500 Close",x="Date")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

    grid.arrange(p1)
```

Here is the formats of all the data that make this plot:

```
> str(matches.df)
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ ddatesmatches: Date, format: "1929-10-28" "1929-11-11" "1929-11-20" "1931-06-08" ...
> str(ddate)
 Date[1:23539], format: "1928-01-03" "1928-01-04" "1928-01-05" "1928-01-06" "1928-01-07" "1928-01-09" "1928-01-10" "1928-01-11" ...
> str(SP500close1)
 num [1:23539] 17.8 17.7 17.6 17.7 17.7 ...
```

As you can see.... both dates are in the Date format and my Y axis (SP500close1) is a numerical value.

Seems a simple thing to add to this chart. Since my formats are where they need to be, can anyone shed some insight into this?

Note - They are however from two different data sources, so i specified in geom_vline(data=matches.df.... in order to read the data to plot the vlines from that specific data frame.

Any insight appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the data for plotdataframe

```
         ddate SP500close1
1   1928-01-03       17.76
2   1928-01-04       17.72
3   1928-01-05       17.55
4   1928-01-06       17.66
5   1928-01-07       17.68
6   1928-01-09       17.50
7   1928-01-10       17.37
8   1928-01-11       17.35
9   1928-01-12       17.47
10  1928-01-13       17.58
11  1928-01-14       17.44
12  1928-01-16       17.29
13  1928-01-17       17.30
14  1928-01-18       17.26
15  1928-01-19       17.38
16  1928-01-20       17.48
17  1928-01-21       17.53
18  1928-01-23       17.64
19  1928-01-24       17.71
20  1928-01-25       17.52
21  1928-01-26       17.63
22  1928-01-27       17.69
23  1928-01-28       17.58
24  1928-01-30       17.49
25  1928-01-31       17.57
26  1928-02-01       17.53
27  1928-02-02       17.63
28  1928-02-03       17.40
29  1928-02-04       17.43
30  1928-02-06       17.45
31  1928-02-07       17.44
32  1928-02-08       17.49
33  1928-02-09       17.55
34  1928-02-10       17.54
35  1928-02-11       17.53
36  1928-02-14       17.44
37  1928-02-15       17.40
38  1928-02-16       17.35
39  1928-02-17       17.04
40  1928-02-18       16.99
41  1928-02-20       16.95
42  1928-02-21       17.11
43  1928-02-23       17.13
44  1928-02-24       17.18
45  1928-02-25       17.19
46  1928-02-27       17.11
47  1928-02-28       17.16
48  1928-02-29       17.26
49  1928-03-01       17.30
50  1928-03-02       17.30
51  1928-03-03       17.42
52  1928-03-05       17.57
53  1928-03-06       17.67
54  1928-03-07       17.58
55  1928-03-08       17.64
56  1928-03-09       17.93
57  1928-03-10       17.87
58  1928-03-12       18.00
59  1928-03-13       17.92
60  1928-03-14       17.93
61  1928-03-15       18.07
62  1928-03-16       18.26
63  1928-03-17       18.32
64  1928-03-19       18.36
65  1928-03-20       18.46
66  1928-03-21       18.65
67  1928-03-22       18.60
68  1928-03-23       18.78
69  1928-03-24       18.79
70  1928-03-26       19.05
71  1928-03-27       18.94
72  1928-03-28       18.89
73  1928-03-29       18.95
74  1928-03-30       19.28
75  1928-03-31       19.13
76  1928-04-02       18.91
77  1928-04-03       19.02
78  1928-04-04       18.99
79  1928-04-05       19.23
80  1928-04-09       19.27
81  1928-04-10       19.10
82  1928-04-11       19.44
83  1928-04-12       19.41
84  1928-04-13       19.73
85  1928-04-14       19.59
86  1928-04-16       19.68
87  1928-04-17       19.52
88  1928-04-18       19.52
89  1928-04-19       19.63
90  1928-04-20       19.34
91  1928-04-23       19.15
92  1928-04-24       19.25
93  1928-04-25       19.33
94  1928-04-26       19.47
95  1928-04-27       19.68
96  1928-04-28       19.75
97  1928-04-30       19.75
98  1928-05-01       19.78
99  1928-05-02       19.83
100 1928-05-03       19.93
101 1928-05-04       20.24
102 1928-05-07       20.41
103 1928-05-08       20.27
104 1928-05-09       20.24
105 1928-05-10       20.21
106 1928-05-11       20.36
107 1928-05-14       20.44
108 1928-05-15       20.39
109 1928-05-16       20.05
110 1928-05-17       20.12
111 1928-05-18       19.92
112 1928-05-21       19.63
113 1928-05-22       19.36
114 1928-05-23       19.75
115 1928-05-24       19.87
116 1928-05-25       19.90
117 1928-05-28       19.57
118 1928-05-29       19.82
119 1928-05-31       20.00
120 1928-06-01       20.07
121 1928-06-02       20.22
122 1928-06-04       19.80
123 1928-06-05       19.85
124 1928-06-06       19.66
125 1928-06-07       19.61
126 1928-06-08       19.37
127 1928-06-09       19.12
128 1928-06-11       18.68
129 1928-06-12       18.34
130 1928-06-13       18.89
131 1928-06-14       19.05
132 1928-06-15       18.74
133 1928-06-16       18.75
134 1928-06-18       18.40
135 1928-06-19       18.34
136 1928-06-20       18.57
137 1928-06-21       18.56
138 1928-06-22       18.54
139 1928-06-23       18.46
140 1928-06-25       18.47
141 1928-06-26       18.68
142 1928-06-27       18.86
143 1928-06-28       19.07
144 1928-06-29       19.14
145 1928-06-30       19.19
146 1928-07-02       18.98
147 1928-07-03       19.29
148 1928-07-05       19.48
149 1928-07-06       19.39
150 1928-07-07       19.44
151 1928-07-09       19.46
152 1928-07-10       19.43
153 1928-07-11       18.95
154 1928-07-12       18.81
155 1928-07-13       18.96
156 1928-07-14       18.93
157 1928-07-16       18.70
158 1928-07-17       18.80
159 1928-07-18       19.03
160 1928-07-19       18.99
161 1928-07-20       19.03
162 1928-07-21       18.96
163 1928-07-23       19.12
164 1928-07-24       19.09
165 1928-07-25       19.20
166 1928-07-26       19.24
167 1928-07-27       19.42
168 1928-07-28       19.47
169 1928-07-30       19.47
170 1928-07-31       19.43
171 1928-08-01       19.42
172 1928-08-02       19.33
173 1928-08-03       19.36
174 1928-08-04       19.41
175 1928-08-06       19.58
176 1928-08-07       19.49
177 1928-08-08       19.25
178 1928-08-09       19.30
179 1928-08-10       19.25
180 1928-08-11       19.30
181 1928-08-13       19.29
182 1928-08-14       19.13
183 1928-08-15       19.47
184 1928-08-16       19.61
185 1928-08-17       19.64
186 1928-08-18       19.71
187 1928-08-20       19.77
188 1928-08-21       20.02
189 1928-08-22       20.00
190 1928-08-23       20.02
191 1928-08-24       20.34
192 1928-08-25       20.45
193 1928-08-27       20.38
194 1928-08-28       20.54
195 1928-08-29       20.58
196 1928-08-30       20.61
197 1928-08-31       20.87
198 1928-09-01       20.87
199 1928-09-04       20.97
200 1928-09-05       21.07
201 1928-09-06       20.94
202 1928-09-07       21.09
203 1928-09-08       21.03
204 1928-09-10       20.92
205 1928-09-11       21.08
206 1928-09-12       21.16
207 1928-09-13       21.14
208 1928-09-14       21.14
209 1928-09-15       21.23
210 1928-09-17       21.33
211 1928-09-18       21.18
212 1928-09-19       21.18
213 1928-09-20       21.22
214 1928-09-21       21.36
215 1928-09-22       21.24
216 1928-09-24       21.43
217 1928-09-25       21.41
218 1928-09-26       21.40
219 1928-09-27       21.13
220 1928-09-28       21.14
221 1928-09-29       21.37
222 1928-10-01       21.36
223 1928-10-02       21.26
224 1928-10-03       21.19
225 1928-10-04       21.26
226 1928-10-05       21.22
227 1928-10-06       21.17
228 1928-10-08       21.11
229 1928-10-09       21.18
230 1928-10-10       21.41
231 1928-10-11       21.51
232 1928-10-13       21.63
233 1928-10-15       21.65
234 1928-10-16       21.72
235 1928-10-17       21.79
236 1928-10-18       21.84
237 1928-10-19       21.96
238 1928-10-20       21.84
239 1928-10-22       21.81
240 1928-10-23       21.95
241 1928-10-24       21.99
242 1928-10-25       21.91
243 1928-10-26       21.65
244 1928-10-27       21.87
245 1928-10-29       22.00
246 1928-10-30       21.76
247 1928-10-31       21.68
248 1928-11-01       21.99
249 1928-11-02       21.95
250 1928-11-03       21.97
251 1928-11-05       22.24
252 1928-11-07       22.50
253 1928-11-08       22.39
254 1928-11-09       22.55
255 1928-11-10       22.73
256 1928-11-12       22.84
257 1928-11-13       22.91
258 1928-11-14       22.91
259 1928-11-15       23.03
260 1928-11-16       23.37
261 1928-11-17       23.37
262 1928-11-19       23.37
263 1928-11-20       23.57
264 1928-11-21       23.22
265 1928-11-22       23.52
266 1928-11-23       23.70
267 1928-11-26       23.80
268 1928-11-27       23.91
269 1928-11-28       24.19
270 1928-11-30       24.28
271 1928-12-01       24.03
272 1928-12-03       23.85
273 1928-12-04       23.91
274 1928-12-05       23.81
275 1928-12-06       22.91
276 1928-12-07       22.36
277 1928-12-08       21.92
278 1928-12-10       22.31
279 1928-12-11       22.74
280 1928-12-12       22.52
281 1928-12-13       22.48
282 1928-12-14       22.53
283 1928-12-15       22.52
284 1928-12-17       22.44
285 1928-12-18       22.70
286 1928-12-19       22.98
287 1928-12-20       23.07
288 1928-12-21       23.33
289 1928-12-22       23.33
290 1928-12-24       23.54
291 1928-12-26       23.44
292 1928-12-27       23.64
293 1928-12-28       23.98
294 1928-12-29       24.05
295 1928-12-31       24.35
296 1929-01-02       24.81
297 1929-01-03       24.86
298 1929-01-04       24.85
299 1929-01-05       24.57
300 1929-01-07       24.25
301 1929-01-08       24.17
302 1929-01-09       24.54
303 1929-01-10       24.58
304 1929-01-11       24.54
305 1929-01-12       24.47
306 1929-01-14       24.59
307 1929-01-15       24.23
308 1929-01-16       24.56
309 1929-01-17       24.69
310 1929-01-18       24.77
311 1929-01-19       24.88
312 1929-01-21       24.86
313 1929-01-22       25.07
314 1929-01-23       25.22
315 1929-01-24       25.06
316 1929-01-25       25.48
317 1929-01-26       25.43
318 1929-01-28       25.35
319 1929-01-29       25.36
320 1929-01-30       25.45
321 1929-01-31       25.74
322 1929-02-01       25.84
323 1929-02-02       25.80
324 1929-02-04       25.64
325 1929-02-05       25.70
326 1929-02-06       25.49
327 1929-02-07       24.71
328 1929-02-08       24.44
329 1929-02-11       24.98
330 1929-02-13       24.95
331 1929-02-14       24.85
332 1929-02-15       24.35
333 1929-02-16       24.05
334 1929-02-18       24.39
335 1929-02-19       24.38
336 1929-02-20       24.59
337 1929-02-21       24.86
338 1929-02-25       24.91
339 1929-02-26       24.95
340 1929-02-27       25.25
341 1929-02-28       25.59
342 1929-03-01       25.83
343 1929-03-02       25.77
344 1929-03-04       25.49
345 1929-03-05       25.32
346 1929-03-06       24.92
347 1929-03-07       25.15
348 1929-03-08       25.31
349 1929-03-09       25.31
350 1929-03-11       24.95
351 1929-03-12       24.97
352 1929-03-13       25.24
353 1929-03-14       25.73
354 1929-03-15       26.08
355 1929-03-16       26.13
356 1929-03-18       26.04
357 1929-03-19       26.03
358 1929-03-20       26.02
359 1929-03-21       25.90
360 1929-03-22       25.55
361 1929-03-23       25.21
362 1929-03-25       24.51
363 1929-03-26       24.35
364 1929-03-27       25.09
365 1929-03-28       25.53
366 1929-04-01       24.88
367 1929-04-02       25.17
368 1929-04-03       24.86
369 1929-04-04       25.30
370 1929-04-05       25.05
371 1929-04-06       25.07
372 1929-04-08       24.83
373 1929-04-09       24.63
374 1929-04-10       24.78
375 1929-04-11       25.06
376 1929-04-12       25.15
377 1929-04-13       25.17
378 1929-04-15       25.00
379 1929-04-16       25.06
380 1929-04-17       25.32
381 1929-04-18       25.43
382 1929-04-19       25.41
383 1929-04-20       25.45
384 1929-04-22       25.70
385 1929-04-23       25.85
386 1929-04-24       25.75
387 1929-04-25       25.63
388 1929-04-26       25.58
389 1929-04-27       25.65
390 1929-04-29       25.53
391 1929-04-30       25.94
392 1929-05-01       25.99
393 1929-05-02       26.11
394 1929-05-03       26.37
395 1929-05-04       26.48
396 1929-05-06       26.32
397 1929-05-07       26.07
398 1929-05-08       26.18
399 1929-05-09       26.02
400 1929-05-10       26.34
401 1929-05-11       26.24
402 1929-05-13       25.64
403 1929-05-14       25.95
404 1929-05-15       25.84
405 1929-05-16       25.97
406 1929-05-17       26.09
407 1929-05-18       26.05
408 1929-05-20       25.39
409 1929-05-21       25.70
410 1929-05-22       24.76
411 1929-05-23       25.31
412 1929-05-24       25.12
413 1929-05-25       25.03
414 1929-05-27       24.20
415 1929-05-28       24.59
416 1929-05-29       24.62
417 1929-05-31       24.83
418 1929-06-01       24.92
419 1929-06-03       25.27
420 1929-06-04       25.64
421 1929-06-05       25.59
422 1929-06-06       25.64
423 1929-06-07       25.53
424 1929-06-08       25.39
425 1929-06-10       25.27
426 1929-06-11       25.43
427 1929-06-12       25.45
428 1929-06-13       25.84
429 1929-06-14       25.93
430 1929-06-15       26.05
431 1929-06-17       26.41
432 1929-06-18       26.42
433 1929-06-19       26.32
434 1929-06-20       26.47
435 1929-06-21       26.62
436 1929-06-22       26.72
437 1929-06-24       26.62
438 1929-06-25       26.90
439 1929-06-26       27.06
440 1929-06-27       27.11
441 1929-06-28       27.41
442 1929-06-29       27.62
443 1929-07-01       27.77
444 1929-07-02       28.06
445 1929-07-03       28.18
446 1929-07-05       28.32
447 1929-07-06       28.36
448 1929-07-08       28.37
449 1929-07-09       28.28
450 1929-07-10       28.20
451 1929-07-11       28.26
452 1929-07-12       28.57
453 1929-07-13       28.64
454 1929-07-15       28.45
455 1929-07-16       28.65
456 1929-07-17       28.72
457 1929-07-18       28.66
458 1929-07-19       28.76
459 1929-07-20       28.81
460 1929-07-22       28.43
461 1929-07-23       28.83
462 1929-07-24       28.64
463 1929-07-25       28.77
464 1929-07-26       28.66
465 1929-07-27       28.55
466 1929-07-29       28.18
467 1929-07-30       28.50
468 1929-07-31       28.88
469 1929-08-01       29.08
470 1929-08-02       29.56
471 1929-08-03       29.81
472 1929-08-05       29.54
473 1929-08-06       29.43
474 1929-08-07       29.13
475 1929-08-08       29.47
476 1929-08-09       28.38
477 1929-08-10       28.83
478 1929-08-12       29.27
479 1929-08-13       29.53
480 1929-08-14       29.62
481 1929-08-15       29.67
482 1929-08-16       30.22
483 1929-08-17       30.24
484 1929-08-19       30.50
485 1929-08-20       30.68
486 1929-08-21       30.55
487 1929-08-22       30.79
488 1929-08-23       31.09
489 1929-08-24       31.15
490 1929-08-26       31.07
491 1929-08-27       31.05
492 1929-08-28       30.99
493 1929-08-29       31.29
494 1929-08-30       31.71
495 1929-09-03       31.82
496 1929-09-04       31.72
497 1929-09-05       31.02
498 1929-09-06       31.83
499 1929-09-07       31.92
500 1929-09-09       31.67
```

And for the matches.df

```
     ddatesmatches
1  1929-10-28
2  1929-11-11
3  1929-11-20
```

Comment: I don't see that error. But I do see that the dates in `matches.df` are later than the maximum date in `plotdataframe`.

Comment: yeah i only pasted a sample too big for here,

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by adding: scale_x_date()+ to the code

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=plotdataframe, aes(x=ddate, y=SP500close1, colour=SP500close1)) + 
  scale_x_date()+
  geom_vline(data=matches.df,aes(xintercept=as.numeric(ddatesmatches)))+
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title="S&P500 Close",y="S&P500 Close",x="Date")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

    grid.arrange(p1)
```